# How to dynamically add/send requests in postman

Tags: postman

Based on test data, is there a way to add/send requests in postman?

Say, I'm submitting answers via POST request and number of POST requests depends on number of questions. As the selected topic or activity(read via environment variable) can have varied questions, fixing up number of requests in the postman sandbox is not possible.

**Scenario:**

[image]

As mentioned in the screenshot, 'GET Wordlist Details' call in the collection fetches me the details of a word list where in I get the number of words and other respective details. As the number of words in each word list can vary, I would like to  dyamically(on the fly) add the subsequenct 'POST' requests which is about submitting answers for each word.

I thought of using 'pm.sendRequest' function inside the 'GET Wordlist Details' call but it can get messy as the purpose of that function is to send asynchronous requests and in this case I will have to submit word by word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share an example of what that currently looks like?

Comment: @DannyDainton - Refer the screenshot above.  'GET Wordlist Details' call fetches me the details of a word list where in I get the number of words and other respective details. As the number of words in each word list can vary, I want to dyamically(on the fly) add the subsequenct 'POST' requests which is about submitting answers for each word. I thought of using 'pm.sendRequest' function inside the 'GET Wordlist Details' but it can get messy as the purpose of that function is to send asynchronous requests and in this case I will have to submit word by word.

Comment: You're explaining more about what you want and what you thought about doing in the comment section. You need to update the question with these details, that's where you should be discribing stuff.

Comment: @DannyDainton -  I have updated the question. BTW, do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Postman I would suggest to use request chaining. In a collection you would have 2 request, your GET and your POST then do something like the following:

1. Create a variable `index` that starts at 0 and a variable with the length of the list of words.
2. GET Wordlist Details then retrieve the first word and store to a `word` variable, increase your index and check that you're not at the end of the array.
3. POST executes with the word stored in the `word` variable then `setNextRequest` to the GET request again and the loop will continue until the end of the array. You'll also need to check if you're at the end of the array (possibly another variable) to not set the next request again otherwise you'll end up in an infinite loop.

This assumes that your list of words is static at least for the duration of the test. If that's not the case you can still take a similar approach by making a single GET request, storing the entire list into a variable then looping through it in the POST request and setting the next request to itself.